# How to make cargo to save-analysis?

Tags: rust, analysis, rust-cargo

How can I make cargo to `save-analysis`? I know that [I can do this with `rustc`](https://users.rust-lang.org/clicks/track?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnrc%2Frls-analysis%2Fissues%2F76&post_id=42801&topic_id=11935) by calling

```
rustc -Zsave-snalysis <files...>
```

But, I couldn't figure out for `cargo`. And also I like to know how I can read them back to `rls_analysis` data structures.

I tried [`cargo rustc -Zsave-analysis`](https://github.com/nrc/rust-dxr/issues/25), but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried [`export RUSTC_SAVE_ANALYSIS=api`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/50022/files#diff-4bc384d35e57dc577b9378d4d733d7c3L760), no work too.

What I want to do is getting fully qualified path (e.g. `::foo1::foo2::Foo3`) to the types notated in source code. If there's other solution, please let me know that too.

Comment: That strange, it should work, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8319ef5b78a10b3a8de4109bb8b0e6d23fbe4de1/src/bootstrap/bin/rustc.rs#L191

Comment: @Stargateur Yes strange, but it doesn't work. Maybe only for `rustc`, not `cargo`. FYI, I'm using nightly `rustc 1.27.0-nightly (2f2a11dfc 2018-05-16)`.

Answer (score 1):

[Just do this](https://github.com/steveklabnik/rustdoc/blob/94f57807eae84207fc02e6855f118f2ba1636d0d/src/cargo.rs#L112) before calling `cargo build`.

```
export RUSTFLAGS="-Z save-analysis"
```

---

Update

Saved analysis data won't be loaded with default configuration of `AnalysisHost`. It's because [`CargoAnalysisLoader` tries to load data from non-default location](https://github.com/nrc/rls-analysis/blob/08f5aad9143485d1d8b6f41e8c938764094d35f0/src/loader.rs#L83).

To workaround, just move `save-analysis` directory to proper location.

```
target/debug/deps/save-analysis
target/rls/debug/deps/save-analysis
```

- Replace `debug` to `release` according to your build mode.